# How to set a group's name of objects on Here Maps

Tags: javascript, here-api

I just wanna set a group's name of objects on Here Maps. Looks simple, but i can not.

I need set this name when this group is created. With this i can remove it after.

Looking in official documentation, the Group[object] have this option 'removeObject(object)' but i can understand how i can call a specific group if i'm not setting the name, or ID.

To create a new group it's necessary do this
var group = new H.map.Group();

So, it's all.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just keep the 'var group' as a global variable and you can use it as it is for any manipulation. It does not need an Id or name.

Comment: Not sure if i understood correctly, but you can create more groups .. var group1=new H.map.Group(); var group2=new H.map.Group();  etc..